# Understanding nested lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested-lists

I am having a bit of trouble understanding what a **one-level list**, **two-level list** and a **three-level list** is. I want to just *eye-ball* it and know it is one or the other, but I am getting confused with the brackets.

What defines levels in a list?

Is this considered a three-level list?

```
​[ [[5,6],7], 9]
```

Or is this a three-level list?

```
​[ [7,2], [[2,3],4], [[[5,6],7],9] ]
```

Comment: `[ [7,2] , [[2,3],4] , [[[5,6],7],9] ]` has a missing closing bracket.

Comment: A list is one level. A list in a list is two levels. A list in a list in a list is three. And so on...

Comment: Start with a `0`. Go through the representation of the list from left to right. For a `[` add `1`, for a `]` subtract `1`. The highest number you reach ist the level. If you end up with something else than `0`, then there is something wrong.

Comment: @Helloimjs0n is your question answered? Are there still things unclear?

Comment: @timgeb Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of nested lists is not terribly complicated, it just means that you can have a list inside of a list. In that list, you could have another list, and so on.

The terms one-level, two-level or n-level list are not widely used, it is more common to use the term nesting level. So let's write a small algorithm to visualize nesting levels:

```
>>> def nestprint(lst, level=0):
...     print('{} is at nesting level {}'.format(lst, level))
...     for item in lst:
...         if isinstance(item, list):
...             nestprint(item, level+1)
```

For a given list, this will print out the nesting level of each list. Here is what it does for your examples:

```
>>> nestprint([[[5,6],7],9])
[[[5, 6], 7], 9] is at nesting level 0
[[5, 6], 7] is at nesting level 1
[5, 6] is at nesting level 2
>>>    
>>> nestprint([[7,2],[[2,3],4],[[[5,6],7],9]])
[[7, 2], [[2, 3], 4], [[[5, 6], 7], 9]] is at nesting level 0
[7, 2] is at nesting level 1
[[2, 3], 4] is at nesting level 1
[2, 3] is at nesting level 2
[[[5, 6], 7], 9] is at nesting level 1
[[5, 6], 7] is at nesting level 2
[5, 6] is at nesting level 3
```

Hopefully this clears things up for you.

Comment: Of course, a wonderful way to blow up this naive function is to pass it a recursive list. `a = []; a.insert(0, a); nestprint(a)`

Answer (score 0):

A basic list in python:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
```

A list inside a list:

```
[1, 2, [1, 2]];
```

A list inside a list inside a list:

```
[1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2]]];
```

You can go on like that forever

Answer (score 0):

When one talks about levels in some kind of container (such as list, tuple, or dict) one is talking about nesting.  So a one-level list doesn't contain other lists in it:

```
one_level = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Once you have added a list into another list, you have a two-level list:

```
two_level[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

and so on and so forth:

```
three_level = [[1, 2, 3], [[4, 5], [6, 7]], [8, 9, 10]]

four_level = [[[['this', 'that']], 'these'], 'those']
```

As you can see, the order of the nesting doesn't matter, only the depth of the nesting.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to think about it is in the sense of containers.

In a one dimensional list/array think of it as a single box containing data.
so for example

```
my_li = [1,2,3]
```

is a box containing values 1,2,3.

A two dimensional list is like a box inside another box. If you open the first box, you'll find many other boxes inside containing information.

```
my_li_two = [[1],[2],[3]]
```

is a box containing 3 boxes each holding a single value.

A third level or 3 dimensional list is just like the 2 dimensional list except now it's a big box containing boxes containing boxes of values.

```
my_li_three = [[[1,2]],[[3]]]
```

any extra layers or levels will just add more boxes to this analogy.